# PHP Ternary Operator with Dates to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, ternary-operator

I'm doing a basic sql string builder, and I'm trying to use ternary operators to conditionally feed a null value, or the value of the datetime into the statement.

Basic syntax of the update statement if all values are present.

```
UPDATE tblRecvLog
SET ScheduledTime = 'datetime',
    ScaleInTime = 'datetime',
    SampleToLabTime = 'datetime',
    ScaleWeight = 'weight',
    SealTop = 'sealnumber',
    SealBottom = 'sealnumber'
 WHERE pkRecvLogID = 'uniqueid';
```

I'm receiving these values from an ajax post, and they're valid values in my $_POST data, all of the encoding and decoding being done appropriately.  When a datetime is not specified on the form and the user submits an update to the table record, I want to write a null value to the database.  I'm trying to properly use ternary operator in my sql string builder to make this work.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblRecvLog SET "
            . ($ScheduledTime == '') ? "ScheduledTime = NULL," : "ScheduledTime = '{$ScheduledTime}',"
            . ($ScaleInTime == '') ? "ScaleInTime = NULL," : "ScaleInTime = '{$ScaleInTime}',"
            . ($SampleToLabTime == '') ? "SampleToLabTime = NULL," : "SampleToLabTime = '{$SampleToLabTime}',"
            . "ScaleWeight = '{$ScaleWeight}',
            SealTop = '{$SealTop}',
            SealBottom = '{$SealBottom}'
        WHERE pkRecvLogID = '{$pkRecvLogID}'";
```

The part I'm not wrapping my head around:

- Dates need to be wrapped in '' for SQL server.
- My use of ' and " is making it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) for this sort of thing, I think it makes things nicer to read. You can read more about the [format specifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters). In this example I am just using `%s` to represent strings.

```
<?php
$query = "
UPDATE 
  tblRecvLog 
SET 
  ScheduledTime = %s, 
  ScaleInTime = %s, 
  SampleToLabTime = %s, 
  ScaleWeight = '%s', 
  SealTop = '%s', 
  SealBottom = '%s'
WHERE 
  pkRecvLogID = '%s';";

$values = [
  ($ScheduledTime == '')  ? NULL : "'" . $ScheduledTime . "'",
  ($ScaleInTime == '')    ? NULL : "'" . $ScaleInTime . "'",
  ($SampleToLabTime = '') ? NULL : "'" . $SampleToLabTime . "'",
  $ScaleWeight,
  $SealTop,
  $SealBottom,
  $pkRecvLogID,
];

$sql = vsprintf($query, $values);
```

Comment: "'" . $ScheduledTime . "'",  I don't know why I didn't think of writing it that way 
 vsprintf does look cleaner.  Will be back tomorrow after some testing. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
$vars = array(
    "ScheduledTime" => $ScheduledTime,
    "ScaleInTime" => $ScaleInTime,
    "SampleToLabTime" => $SampleToLabTime,
    "ScaleWeight" => $ScaleWeight
    "SealTop" => $SealTop,
    "SealBottom" => $SealBottom
);

$set = array();
foreach($vars as $k => $v)
{
    if ($v == '' || is_null($v))
    {
        $set[] = sprintf("`%s` = NULL", $k);
    } else {
        $set[] = sprintf("`%s` = '%s'", $k, $v);
    }
}

$set = implode(', ', $set);

if ($set != "")
{
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE `tblRecvLog` SET %s WHERE `pkRecvLogID` = '%s'", $set, $pkRecvLogID);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it this way I may have reason to store other values as nulls, making the foreach possibly worth it.  Will be back tomorrow after some testing.  Thanks,

Comment: Another alternative, a helper function: `function null_or_val($v) { return $v == '' || is_null($v) ? "NULL" : "'".$val."'"; }`. You could use it like `... SET myField = ".null_or_value($myField)." ...`